# How to simplify long cascaded sentences?

Tags: grammar

In programming languages it is very common to write sentences which would literally translate to:

> Take the wrench in the fourth row from the bottom of the shelf of the cupboard,  in the bedroom, in my house and place it in trunk of the red car with green lights.
>
> His father's, brother's, aunt's, sister's, child is the friend of my mother's, sister's, aunt's, child.

The above statements are make believe and extreme examples but they get the point across.

My programmer friends have no difficulty parsing sentences like these but other people get totally confused when I do so.

The problem is, it has become so natural for me to use statements like these that I often have no clue how to break these sentences down without literally handing them a checklist in a piece of paper.

What general strategies can be implemented to break down sentences like this into something grammatically correct?

Comment: The best "general strategy", must surely be to learn English through exposure to the actual language as used by native speakers, not extrapolating its principles from artificially-designed *programming* languages.

Comment: Firstly, all languages are artificially designed. So, basically you are asking me to read more books and talk to people?

Comment: @SouradeepNanda First, no, only artificial languages are artificial. We have the term "natural language" for a reason. A natural language is no more "designed" than a tree.  Second, yes, the best general strategy for becoming proficient in a language is practice, specifically talking to native speakers. Reading helps as well, it exposes you to many good examples. Also, it's worth noting that "grammatically correct" has a specific technical meaning. Both your sentences are *grammatically* correct, even if people find them confusing. You're asking about style, not grammar.

Comment: No, most language are not designed, they don't follow a masterplan and have rigorous rules. They evolve from a more ancient one and by borrowing words or patterns from other languages. One cannot predict or plan what's going to happen with a language: they are not designed, excepted for Esperanto, programming ones and such,

Comment: @Souradeep: You got it! :) But I would point out that your second example illustrates the difference quite clearly, in that you casually invented a non-existent orthographic principle allowing you to include ***commas*** to help readers deconstruct your cascade of possessives. That's only credible because you know that *real people* are going to read your text, and very likely even if we don't find those commas actually *helpful*, at least they won't prevent us *understanding* the text. If you did that with a *computer* language it would just be rejected as "Syntax Error", and not understood.

Comment: Try to simplify your writing by splitting the text in smaller sentences and take advntage of the punctuations. For example, *The wrench is at home in my bedoom cupboard, in the fourth row from the bottom of the shelf. Take it and place it in the trunk of the red car with green lights*.

Comment: I think your awkward sentence could be called a *cluttered* sentence.

Comment: When talking with programmers, we usually say it the other way. "Go to my house, in the bedroom, bottom of the cupboard shelf, fourth row, get the wrench. Put it in the red car with the green lights, in the trunk." Grammar be damned. Clearly communicated. And we all read XKCD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same solution used in programming.

> His father's, brother's, aunt's, sister's, child is the friend of my mother's, sister's, aunt's, child.

Swift translation:

```
let mary = him.father.brother.aunt.sister.child
let bob = me.mother.sister.aunt.child
mary.addReciprocalFriend(bob)
```

Swift refactor:

```
let hisGreatAunt = him.father.brother.aunt
let mary = hisGreatAunt.sister.child
let myGrandmom = me.mother.sister.mother
let bob = myGrandmom.sister.child
mary.addReciprocalFriend(bob)
```

English translation:

> Let me tell you about my this guy Bob, so it turns out that his great aunt and my grandmom both have nieces that know each other. This relationship was too distant to run afoul of any nepotism laws, but we did have fun discussing our family trees. This is my maternal grandmom and ...

Answer (score 3):

You know where the bedroom is in my house? There's a cupboard in it with a wrench on the fourth shelf from the bottom. Take that wrench and put it in the trunk of the red car with green lights.

Comment: But I don't know where your *house* is!